# With C# how can I extract a single image from an animated GIF file?

Tags: c#, graphics

I need to extract a single frame from an animated GIF file. I've got as far as

```
Guid aFrameID = image.FrameDimensionsList[0];
```

but I have no idea what to do with the Guid value to get the corresponding image (as a bitmap, maybe?)

TIA

Comment: The second answer shows how to get every frame from an animated GIF.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly for me.